# instapy Подписатся на человека по айди

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram, instagram-api, instapy

Я хочу что бы я указал ссылку на айди человека,или просто указал айди человека и бот бы подписался на него

```
from instapy import InstaPy
session = InstaPy(username="name", password="password")
session.login()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Держи

```css
from instapy import InstaPy
session = InstaPy(username="ЛОГИН", password="ПАРОЛЬ")
session.login()

id = ["ID ЮЗЕРА"]
session.follow_by_list(followlist=id, times=1, sleep_delay=600, interact=False)
```

Comment: Что значит sleep_delay?

Comment: Опция sleep_delay используется , чтобы определить время перерыва (таймаут) после нескольких успешных подписок.
P.S. В моем коде можно вставить сразу несколько id и бот будет подписываться на каждого, кто указан в контейнере id

Comment: Помогло? Если да, то поставь пожалуйста  галочку на мой ответ.

Comment: щяс прийду домой, буду испытывать